# Method names for getting data containing a filter argument

Tags: .net, methods, naming-conventions

Me and our developers are no native english speakers and are not sure how to name methods that have arguments that are used to filter the return value.

Here are some example from our .NET code:

```
GetUserByRoleId(string roleId);

GetUsersFromGroupId(string groupId);

GetUserByGivenLicenseId(string licenseId);
```

- By
- From
- ByGiven
- FromGiven

What is a good convention to name such methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `...By...` because it is

- correct
- meaningful
- concise

However, i think this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thank you. `..By..` is really my favorite too. Grüße nach Aachen :)